# How to read multiple Boolean operators at once in C++

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm trying to find the result (True or  False) of:

```
x = 7, y = 10, z = 12

((!(x < z) || (y > z)) && (z==12) && (y==10))
```

but I'm having trouble reading it. For example would it be the or statement AND the result of the two and statements?

Comment: Have a look at the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules.

Comment: Operator precedence rules are not even useful in this case, because every expression is delimited by parenthesis.

Comment: In this case there are clearly parantheses around the OR expression right? Is it not clear that this means it is evaluated first and the result evaluted with the operator outside the parantheses? I don't folow what your problem with this particular example is.

Comment: "For example would it be the or statement AND the result of the two and statements?" -- If you're asking whether `(a || b) && c && d` means `((a || b) && c) && d` or `(a || b) && (c && d)`: that doesn't make any difference whatsoever. If that's not what you're asking, please help us understand by explaining in a bit more detail which aspect is confusing you.

Comment: If you remove the superfluous parentheses you are left with: `(!(x < z) || y > z) && z == 12 && y == 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
((!(x < z) || (y > z)) && (z==12) && (y==10))
((!(7 < 12) || (10 > 12)) && (12==12) && (10==10))
((!(true) || false) && true && true)
((false || false) && true && true)
(false && true && true)
false
```